# how to retrieve all information about a process?

Tags: command-line

In process-explorer the mouse-over shows all the properties of a running service.

[image]

Which commandline command outputs all this information?

Comment: Retrieving *all* properties is kind of pointless. The tooltip only contains the command line anyway. If possible you should name the properties you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `WMIC` command to get this information.

Use `wmic process` on command prompt to get details of all processes running at your system. This also includes command line details of process. You can redirect output to file or can filter output by process name or id. More details can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx).